# Trying to call a function via a pointer to a smart pointer to a COM interface

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

I followed the Microsoft tutorial [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736/en-us) (with a little help from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892602/is-this-tlh-file-correct-and-if-not-then-how-do-i-generate-the-correct-one)) to call a COM object from C++ code.

Step 9 of the tutorial says:

> To call the managed DLL, add the following code to the _tmain
>   function:

```
// Initialize COM.
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

// Create the interface pointer.
ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));
```

When I used these lines of code in my file, they worked fine, and I called functions on the COM interface successfully.

Now, I need to access pICalc in 2 static functions, so I thought of making it a static class variable (I am aware that static has 2 different meanings in this sentence).

This is my code:

In MyCPlusPlusClass.h:

```
static ICalculatorPtr* pICalc;
```

In MyCPlusPlusClass.cpp:

```
//Pointer definition
ICalculatorPtr* MyCPlusPlusClass::pICalc;
```

and in a static function:

```
pICalc = new ICalculatorPtr(__uuidof(ManagedClass));
```

but when I tried to call a function with

```
(*pICalc)->SomeICalcFunction();
```

I got

> _com_issue_error(Int32)  at _com_ptr_t ...

I'm mostly a C# programmer, so am I just making a stupid syntax mistake in C++?

EDIT:
In the .tlh file, there is

```
struct __declspec(uuid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")) _ManagedClass

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ICalc, __uuidof(ICalc));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_ManagedClass, __uuidof(_ManagedClass));

virtual HRESULT __stdcall SomeICalcFunction (BSTR * pRetVal) = 0;
```

Comment: Can you find ManagedDLL.tlh, ManagedDLL.tli and paste content of this files ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you call the static function with pICalc initialisation before calling SomeICalcFunction?

Comment: @Wojteksurowka - yes, because I call SomeICalcFunction inside the static initialisation function, i.e. it is the next line after initialising pICalc.

Comment: @user2451677 - I added some relevant lines from the .tlh file.  Please note, that it worked perfectly when I created and used the interface pointer locally, like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think, that you must do the following.

In MyCPlusPlusClass.h:

change

```
static ICalcPtr* pICalc;
```

to

```
static ICalcPtr pICalc;
```

In MyCPlusPlusClass.cpp:

change

```
//Pointer definition
ICalcPtr* MyCPlusPlusClass::pICalc;
```

to

```
ICalcPtr MyCPlusPlusClass::pICalc;
```

In all of your static functions:

```
if(pICalc == NULL)
{
    if(FAILED(pICalc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ManagedClass))))
        std::cout << "Can't create pICalc" << std::endl;
}
```

And then use:

```
pICalc->SomeICalcFunction();
```

I really dont understand why you need static functions. Make all them non-static and pICalc non-static too. That will be more cleaner.

Comment: @SList, you need to paste all your C++ code, because constructor of _com_ptr_t (it's the class of pICalc) internally calls CreateInstance(). This means that ICalcPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass)) and ICalcPtr pICalc; pICalc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ManagedClass)) are the same things. You can check this by changing your local variable creation.